# Running "su command" as another user

Tags: linux, files, rhel, sudo, passwd

I have a user `user1` which is part of `wheel group` and has all the `root privileges` .

`user1` is able to change password for `user2` using the below command
(My understanding is that here `passwd` is run as `root`):

```
[user1@rhel-85 ~]$ sudo passwd user2
```

However, when `user1` tries to run `passwd` as `user2`, I am getting an error:

```
[user1@rhel-85 ~]$ su -u user2 passwd
Try 'su --help' for more information.
[user1@rhel-85 ~]$
```

Comment: You seem to confuse `sudo` and `su`. These two programs have different command line syntax and slightly different purpose. Do you mean `sudo -u user2 passwd`?

Comment: You are right. This is working fine `sudo -u user2 passwd`. By the way, can you please help understand difference between `sudo` and `su`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

su is used to launch a root shell that allows all further commands to use root access. `su` has no -u option...

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html

This is why it is saying/complains;

> Try 'su --help' for more information.

You would need to add user1 to the wheel group, then as Bodo points out, execute;

```
sudo -u user2 passwd
```

It's clear to me that sudo is your intended use here, as you are trying to execute a single command with temporary privilege elevation. (which is what sudo is for).

However, for completeness and as user Bib points out, you could execute;

```
su - _user_ foo
```

...which would allow you to run as root for another user.

This is the 'login shell' option for `su` (`-, -l or --login`). This is also handy for granting root privileges in the scenario, where the user doesn't have `sudo` privileges (and where the admin don't want them to, either.).

Comment: Well, you sure as heck can use `su - _user_` to run a command as another user. It's not limited to root.

Comment: yes, Bib. you can do that. that's the login shell option. I never said that wasn't a possibility or that su was limited to root... i was stating why they got the error and what the difference between su and sudo are.